# How to open sidemenu with different button, something similar to tabs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have one sidemenu whose content will change based on some button clicked.

However, when I click on my second button, the sidemenu will toggle and I have to click again on the button to open the sidemenu.

I want to show my sidemenu like the [OpenStreetMap.org](https://www.openstreetmap.org) sidemenu.

So for example as in the OSM, the sidemenu will switch between the buttons of layer, MapKey, and share with out closing and opening at each click.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to answer without some code from your buttons, but it sounds like the click event is propagating up to the sidemenu. One quick suggestion is that you can stop propagation using ng-click, like this:

`<button ng-click="doSomethingCool(); $event.stopPropagation();"></button>`